# Is there any advantages of defining variable names as __00000001 in C / C++

Tags: c++, c, variable-names

Is there any advantages of defining variable names as __00000001, __00000002, etc.?

Example:

```
int __00000001, __00000002 = 0;
for (__00000001 = 0; __00000001 < 10; __00000001++) {
    __00000002 = __00000002 + __00000001；
}
...
```

Update: this is mentioned in one of my programming classes a few years ago, and I remembered that the professor said there is some advantages of using it. However, I cannot recall any more information. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: That looks like decompiled code. If that's the case, it's just computer generated auto-names. Where did you get this?

Comment: That looks like code that may have been written by code.

Comment: What makes you think there would be?

Comment: If your goal is to make the code less immediately readable or intelligible versus using sensible variable names, then that would be one advantage. Without any other context, it's a vague question.

Comment: For starters, this is illegal C++ code, since the identifier is reserved and mustn't be used.

Comment: @KonradRudolph UB not illegal

Comment: [Here's one reason.](http://dilbert.com/strip/1994-06-10)

Comment: What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: @Kevin There may not be, but this is an interesting question that could start a discussion about naming things, which is always a good thing.

Answer (score 5):

Those particular variable names are not available for user programs:

> All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use. (C11, section 7.1.3, paragraph 1)

So that's a big disadvantage.

Answer (score 4):

Is obfuscating the crap out of your code worthwhile? No, not unless your goal is literally to do just that: to make your code as hard to read as possible. Trouble is, you've got to read it too.

Sometimes you'll run into code like this when somebody's "decompiled" a program — variable names do not survive the compilation process so this is sort of the best a decompiler can do when reconstructing a C++ program. Of course it cannot really reconstruct a C++ program; it can only re-spell the flattened logic in C++ syntax. Oh well.

Addressing your example specifically, it's worth noting that *all* identifiers beginning with two underscores are reserved to the implementation (your compiler and standard library), so [your program has undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/560648).